# Reference a variabled in tasks.json that was defined in launch.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm trying to configure my project in Visual Studio Code.
I am using CMake+make to build my project. CMake needs to know the project configuration (Debug/Release) and architecture (x64/x86) before it can generate the make files.

I could define 4 tasks and 4 launch configurations to achieve this (each hardcoding both options), but that is a lot of duplication.
Instead, I would like to use environment variables to basically "pass down" the parameters from the launch configuration to a single task.

However, VScode doesn't seem to forward what I define in the launch configuration to the task.

Here is what I have:

```
// launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug (x64)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/debug/x64/executable",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "proj_configuration",
                    "value": "Debug"
                },
                {
                    "name": "proj_platform",
                    "value": "x64"
                }
            ],
            // "variables": {
            //     "proj_configuration": "Debug",
            //     "proj_platform": "x64"
            // },
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Make Project",
        }
    ]
}
```

```
// tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmake",
            "args": [
                "-B${workspaceFolder}/build",
                "-H${workspaceFolder}",
                "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${proj_configuration}",
                "-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=${proj_platform}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": false
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Make Project",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "dependsOn": ["Build Project"],
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to run my project, I get

> Executing task: cmake -B/home/user/project/build -H/home/user/project/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${proj_configuration} -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=${proj_platform}

As you can see, the 2 variables are not replaced.
I've also tried using the property "variables", but no luck using that either.

So, is it possible to do what I described, or do I have to define multiple tasks instead?

Answer (score 0):

with the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#remember) you can save a number of strings in a store and use these in launch.json and task.json. See example in the link